# scroll bar acting differently in Firefox, IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroll bar in a table which is working perfectly with no flaw on IE however it's not working as expected in Firefox. It does not hide when row is less than 0 also it looks slightly bigger in Firefox than in IE. Help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
if ($('#tablebody >tr').length > 0) {
  $('#tablebody').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
}
```

```css
.weeklyta tbody {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="weeklyta">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody id="tablebody">
</table>
```

Comment: browsers are unique. thats how it is. Make it work in firefox and chrome, the people who still use IE should change their browser

Comment: Please refrain from using all capital letters. It is interpreted as shouting in many contexts.

Comment: @Jonasw the OP must has his reasons to need IE

Comment: Guys I need this to be working both on IE and firefox. There must be a way to fix. I cant tell people to not use particular browser that does not make any sense

Comment: which version of IE?

Comment: Tom its IE 10 , its working fine in IE, not working as expected on firefox.

Comment: I don't the idea of that snippet. I made this jsfiddle, I see it ok in both IE and FF: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/g86twd50/2/

Comment: Look: http://i.imgur.com/cxkFZg1.gif whats wrong with it?

Comment: pmirnd its working for me too but that's the issue. when row is less than 1 the scroll bar needs to be hidden, working on IE but not in firefox also scroll bar appears slightly larger in firefox than on IE

Comment: @david the scrollbar is a native part of the browser. You cant control what it looks like unless you write a custom javascript implementation. I believe at one time Firefox gave some vendor CSS to control the looks a little but I think they got rid of it. So while you may be able to fix the issue with hiding it when there are only so many rows you cannot change what it looks like without writing a custom implementation.

Comment: thx for info AtheistP3ace